# Convertir un valor de Paste en una variable

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente problema, hago un pegado de caracteres para formar otro caracter de la siguiente manera:

```
paste0("SUMATOT", "VALORES", sep = "")
```

Ahora lo que necesito es convertir ese  pegado en una variable a la que pueda asignarle valores, he utilizado la función `get` pero no funciona:

```
paste0("SUMATOT", "VALORES", sep = "", get) <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

Me lanza el siguiente error

```
Error in paste0("SUMATOT", gsub(" ", "", DATA[1]), sep = "", get) <- SUM : 
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Daniel, No entiendo muy bien la pregunta. A que resultado quieres llegar? Quieres que el vector `c(1,2,3) `sea un objeto cuyo nombre sea `SUMATOTVALORES`?

Comment: Hola, no realmente, quiero generalizar el proceso de obtener un string por medio de paste y que ese string pueda convertirlo en una variable a la cual pueda asignarle un vector, data.frame, lista, etc, ese es el punto.

Comment: Te agradecería bastante si logras ayudarme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entendí correctamente, lo que buscas es nombrar una variable con el resultado de un `paste0()`. Esto lo puedes lograr usando [`assign()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) que te permite "asignar" al entorno actual el nombre de variable indicado en el primer parámetro con el valor del segundo:

```
nombre_variable <- paste0("SUMATOT", "VALORES", sep = "")
assign(nombre_variable, c(1,2,3))

SUMATOTVALORES
[1] 1 2 3
```

**Nota:** No es obligatorio definir primero `nombre_variable` puedes hacerlo en un solo paso.

Si no quieres asignar inicialmente el valor y solo definir el espacio en memoria y el nombre de la variable, solo debes indicar la menos el tipo de valor que piensas guardar:

```
assign(paste0("SUMATOT", "VALORES", sep = ""), numeric(0))
```

Comment: Muchas, muchas gracias.